# Why char returns int

Tags: java

so i've got this piece of code.. is anyone kind enough to explain me why it returns int version and not the String one?

```
class Student13
        {
         void myMethod(int i) {System.out.println("int version");}
         void myMethod(String s) {System.out.println("String version");}
         public static void main(String args[])
         {
                Student13 obj = new Student13();
                char ch = 'c';
                obj.myMethod(ch);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Read section 5.1.2: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a `char` to an `int` is a basic *widening primitive conversion*, specified in the [Java Language Spec 5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).  That conversion is built into the language at a basic level.

On the other hand, there is no direct conversion between `char` and `String`, and if you didn't have the `int` overload, your code would fail to compile.  `char` must be explicitly converted to `String`, by concatenating with `""`, using `Character.toString`, or another technique.

Answer (score 0):

`char`, besides some sugaring on how it's printed, is essentially a integer type. When looking for suitable method, `char` can be widened to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`, and can be autoboxed to `java.lang.Character`.  It can't however, be converted to `java.lang.String`. If that's the behavior you want, you'd have to do it explicitly on your own, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String args[])
 {
        Student13 obj = new Student13();
        char ch = 'c';
        obj.myMethod(String.valueOf(ch));
 }
```